# How to Edit document saved in Elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, urllib3

I am new to `elasticsearch` and I am trying to perform CRUD operations using python. I have created an Index and I am able to save the document in the Elasticsearch. However when I try to update the document, the whole data gets overwritten. For instance, while creating a document there are 3 fields:

```
data = {
 "typeId":"someValue",
 "typeStatus":"someValue",
 "typeLists":"someValue",
 "createdDate","someValue"
}
```

The above gets saved while saving the document. While Editing the above document the createdDate gets deleted. Below is the Update document.

```
data = {
 "typeId":"someValue",
 "typeStatus":"someValueEdited",
 "typeLists":"someValue",
 "updatedDate","someValue"
}
```

Is there a way to save/edit the document without loosing the fields? Below is the code.

```
import urllib3
        
        
saveContext = '_doc'
updateContext = '_update'
httpClient = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = httpClient.request('PUT', 
                          elasticsearchURL, 
                          headers={'headersValue'},
                          body=json.dumps(items))
```

The context values are appended to the ES URL.

Comment: Can you show what you have in the `elasticsearchURL` variable ?

Comment: elasticsearchURL = elasticsearch + saveContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve what you want just not with the same URL.

You can create the document as you do now by hitting the [following endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html)

```
PUT index/_doc/<id>
{
  "typeId": "someValue",
  "typeStatus": "someValue",
  "typeLists": "someValue",
  "createdDate": "someValue"
}
```

Then, when you want to partially update your document, you need to hit a slightly [different endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) (with a slightly different body), which is

```
POST index/_doc/<id>/_update
{
   "doc" : {
     "typeId": "someValue",
     "typeStatus": "someValueEdited",
     "typeLists": "someValue",
     "updatedDate": "someValue"
   }
}
```

Then end result will be:

```
{
  "typeId": "someValue",
  "typeStatus": "someValueEdited",
  "typeLists": "someValue",
  "createdDate": "someValue",
  "updatedDate": "someValue"
}
```

Also note that when updating the document, you don't need to pass the fields whose value haven't changed (i.e `typeId` and `typeLists`)

Comment: The URL is as you suggested but I am getting below error.
`b'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:2] [UpdateRequest] unknown field [typeId]"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[1:2] [UpdateRequest] unknown field [typeId]"},"status":400}'`

Comment: Did you make sure to wrap everything in the `"doc": {...}` structure ?